# How to fix "error: encountered unrecoverable cycle resolving import"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to resolve the following compile error?

```
SOApp.scala:7: error: encountered unrecoverable cycle resolving import.
Note: this is often due in part to a class depending on a definition nested within its companion.
If applicable, you may wish to try moving some members into another object.
  import spark.implicits._
```

Code:

```
object SOApp extends App with Logging {
  // For implicit conversions like converting RDDs to DataFrames
  import spark.implicits._

  import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession  
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("Stackoverflow App")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()
}
```

Comment: Move `import spark.implicits._` after `val spark = SparkSession...getOrCreate()`.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski It worked after moving but I am curious why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**tl;dr** Move `import spark.implicits._` after `val spark = SparkSession...getOrCreate()`.

---

That name `spark` causes a lot of confusion since it could refer to `org.apache.spark` package as well as to `spark` value.

Unlike Java, Scala allows for `import` statements in many more places.

What you could consider a Spark SQL idiom is to create a `spark` value that gives access to implicits. In Scala, you can only bring implicits into scope from stable objects (like values) so the following is correct:

```
  // For implicit conversions like converting RDDs to DataFrames
  import spark.implicits._
```

And as you comment says, it's to bring implicit conversions of RDDs to DataFrames (among the things).

This is not to import `org.apache.spark` package, but for the implicit conversions.

Comment: Can you pls point me to some reading material related to " In Scala, you can only bring implicits into scope from stable objects (like values) so the following is correct:"

Comment: @AravindYarram Tried to find a trusted source, but found none so far. I think I've read about it in the spec, but don't seem lucky today.